# Cordova - jquery mobile img path

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, date, jquery-mobile

I have an img which shows on the main page correctly, but when I navigate to an other page the image will not show up on my phone. In the browser it shows the image as expected. I really don't know what the problem is...

this is the javascript code where I append html to a table :

```
var imgPath = '../img/icons/notification_bell.png';

html = html + "<tr><td class='img-table'><img src=" + imgPath + "/></td>" + "<td><span class='time-aside'><strong>" + formattedTime + "</strong></span><h4>" + info.data[count][1] + "</h4><p>" + info.data[count][2] + "</p></td></tr>";
```

and this is the html:

```
<div data-role="page" id="all">
   <div data-role="header">
       <a href="#dashboard" class="ui-btn ui-icon-carat-l ui-btn-icon-notext ui-alt-icon ui-corner-all ui-btn-left" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">No text</a>
       <h1>All Reminders</h1>
     </div>

        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content" data-theme="b">
         <table data-role="table" data-mode="column" id="notificationTable" class="ui-responsive">
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <a class="clearbtn" style="text-decoration: none"><button>clear</button></a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

When I inspect the image with `chrome://inspect/` i get this error:

```
  /img/icons/notification_bell.png/:1 GET file:///img/icons/notification_bell.png/ net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

And when I set it manually to the same path as on the dashboard like this: `'img/icons/notification_bell.png'` it shows up but when I do it via JS it does not show up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app is in the root folder, try to put only:

```js
var imgPath = 'img/icons/notification_bell.png';
```